# models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

Tags: python, django, models

I have a problem with my models.DateTimeField, because I´m from México and in settings.py I use this:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Mexico_City'
```

But when i add a register in my mysql database, it says that the register added at 18:00 (4 hours later, because here, in Mexico City is 14:00)

```
titulo = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
contenido = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: My Django version is 1.5.1.

Comment: Well, it should work right, because Django since 1.4 supports timezones in a right way - so that `auto_now_add` should just take into account the configured timezone (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.timezone)). Do you have `USE_TZ = True` in settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enable USE_TZ = True, Django then uses UTC for all times in the database.  That is why you are seeing the time 4 hours ahead -- that is UTC time.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

Django has helpers to take the UTC and then convert it back for you when you display it in a view. Try getting an object from the db that uses DateTimeField and try this in a view where `{{ value }}` is the datetime:

```
{% load tz %}

{% localtime on %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}

{% localtime off %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

You might have install pytz as a requirement if you haven't done so already:

```
pip install pytz
```